# Как проверить, подключен ли андроид к wifi?

Tags: java, android, wifi, mobile

Нужен код:
Когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку, идёт проверка покдключен ли он к интернету, если нет - выводится сообщение с двумя вариантами: подключится к интернету ( открываются настройки ) или выйти из приложения.

Comment: подключение к wifi не дает гарантии доступности интернета.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
public boolean checkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
}
```

Только не забудь  в манифесте прописать `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Это определит подключение в общем к интернету, а не только к  wi-fi